# Calling a function on a UITableViewCell before the cell is returned?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have this custom UITableViewCell:

```
class CircleOfTrustTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var permissionTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var permissionImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var permissionSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var spacingView: UIView!

    // Update toggle based on user visibility and category type
    func update(showUser: Bool, index: Int){
        self.tag = index
        let type = ProfileContentTypeActual.all[index]
        self.permissionImage.image = UIImage(named: categoryImages[type]!)
        self.permissionTitle.text = categoryNames[type]
        if showUser {
            self.permissionSwitch.tag = index
            self.permissionSwitch.isEnabled = true

            if let toggles = GlintUser.getThisUser().trust_toggle {
                self.permissionSwitch.setOn(toggles.getState(type), animated: true)
            }
        } else {
            self.permissionSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
            self.permissionSwitch.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

I implement the cell this way:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    settingsTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "COTTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cotCell")
    let cotCell = (settingsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cotCell") as! CircleOfTrustTableViewCell)

    cotCell.update(showUser: showUser, index: indexPath.row)
    return cotCell 
}
```

My question is: Is it best practice to call the update function on the cell (to populate its data) or is it best to leave this in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: FYI - do not call `register` inside the `cellForRow` method. You only need to register a cell once. `viewDidLoad` is a much better place for that line of code.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You are already calling `update` on the cell in the `cellForRowAt` method. The code you posted is basically what you should be doing (except as noted in my first comment).

Comment: Are you asking whether it is bad practice to remove the code from the `tableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath` method and place it in a separate func?  If so, I don't think it really matters. In your scenario it doesn't seem strictly necessary, but if it declutters your class in the long-run, go for it.

Comment: Yes, sorry. To clarify the question, is it ok to remove the code from 'tableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath' and instead call the 'update' function from  my custom cell class? I'm asking because I'm experiencing some 'stickiness' with the UISwitch, and the change happened after finished assigning the outlets via this 'update' method.

Comment: i think you are good to go
https://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/table-views/ and also https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-practices-for-identifying-UITableViewCell  i know your code is swift but the idea is to keep your controller clean